# Localise nested virtual attribute in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localization, globalization

How is it possible to localise **nested virtual attribute** in Rails?

The model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :company_information # This is used in callbacks etc
end
```

and the view:

```
= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), html: {class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f|
  = devise_error_messages!
  = f.input :email
  = f.input :password
  = f.input :password_confirmation
  = f.simple_fields_for :company_information do |c|
    = c.input :name # This is what I want to localise
  = f.button :submit
```

The translation keys (from `en.yml`) like `activerecord.attributes.user.company_information.name` and `activerecord.attributes.user.company_information_name` aren't picked up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using simple_form gem for generation of forms. Here is what worked for me.

```
en:
  simple_form:
    labels:
      user:
        company_information:
          name: My Name
```

The link to simple form's [localization chapter](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#i18n) may be also useful.

Answer (score 0):

In rails 3 i found one way. In your case translation would be `helpers.label.user[company_information].name` in en.yml it would look like this

```
en:
  helpers:
    label:
      "user[company_information]":
        name:"Name"
```

Comment: I tried this solution and while it appears perfectly on the form, if there is a validation error then this isn't picked up and it reverts to the default.

Any suggestions?