# Localisation of attributes in Rails virtual models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, localization, rails-i18n

I've created a virtual (non-persistent) model in Rails 3 (see below)

I now need to apply translations to the model but the standard translations locations don't seem to work. e.g.

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      media_upload:
        title: "My Title"
```

I know I can apply this directly to the label with an optional string parameter eg. `f.label :title, t('activerecord.attributes.media_upload')`  but that doesn't work for error messages resulting from validations. Similarly, I could add a key to the translations file for the label helper as suggested in [Localise nested virtual attribute in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258670/localise-nested-virtual-attribute-in-rails) but this also fails to work for the validations.

```
helpers:
  label:
    media_upload:
      title: "My Title"
```

Apart from redefining all of the relevant validation messages, is there any other way I can do localisation of attributes in non-persistent models??

A sample model is shown below,

```
class MediaUpload
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :media_file, :title

  validates_presence_of :media_file
  validates_presence_of :title

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    unless attributes.nil?
      attributes.each do |name, value|
        send("#{name}=", value)
      end
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

Comment: You have to use the activemodel in place of activerecord in

activerecord.errors.models.admin.attributes.name.blank
activerecord.errors.models.admin.blank
activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes.name.blank
activerecord.errors.models.user.blank
activerecord.errors.messages.blank
errors.attributes.name.blank
errors.messages.blank

For example

  activemodel:
    attributes:
      user:
        login: "Login"
        email: "Email"
        first_name: "First Name"
  
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
           login:
             is_invalid: "^Incorrect login"

Comment: Did you solve this issue ?

Answer (score 5):

You need write like this:

```
en:
  activemodel:
    attributes:
      media_upload:
        title: "My Title"
```

not `activerecord` replace it with `activemodel`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using simple_form gem for generation of forms.

So following [i18n chapter from github](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#i18n) your internationalization file should look like this

```
en:
  simple_form:
    labels:
      media_upload:
        media_file: My File
        title: My Title
```

If you are using Rails 4 than there is an easier way to make [ActiveModel Form Objects](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/activemodel-form-objects/). You can just `include ActiveModel::Model` like so

```rb
class MediaUpload
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :media_file, :title

  validates_presence_of :media_file
  validates_presence_of :title
end
```